# CI Form validation returns false but validaion_errors() is blank

Tags: codeigniter, validation

My Code :

```
public function add()
    {
        if ($this->input->post())
        {
            //echo '<pre>';print_r($this->input->post());exit;
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('agency[title]','Title','required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('agency[first_name]','First Name','trim|required|min_length[3]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('agency[last_name]','Last Name','trim|required|min_length[3]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('agency[email]','Email','trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[agency.email]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','trim|required|min_length[3]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('conf_password','Confirm Password','required|matches[password]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('agency[agency_unique_id]','Agency Unique ID','trim|required|min_length[3]|is_unique[agency.agency_unique_id]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('agency[vat_registered]','VAT Registered','trim|min_length[3]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('agency_profile[address1]','Address 1','trim|required|min_length[3]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('agency_profile[address2]','Address 2','trim');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('agency_profile[address3]','Address 2','trim');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('agency_profile[town]','Town','trim|required|min_length[3]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('agency_profile[postcode]','Post Code','trim|required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('agency_profile[phone]','Phone','trim|required|integer|exact_length[11]');
            $this->form_validation->set_message('is_unique','%s is already Present. Plesae Provide a diffrent value');
            if($this->form_validation->run() != FALSE)
            {
                //i never reach this part..
            }
            else
            {
                echo validation_errors();exit;
                                // no errors is printed on the screen.
            }

        }

        $data['middle'] = 'agency/add';
        $this->load->view('template/template',$data);
    }
```

Comment: can you give us your view code pls

Comment: your field name like this => agency[title]

Answer (score 0):

You need to echo the below statement in  top of **view** page not **controller** page

```
 <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
```

**Controller** page:

```
 if($this->form_validation->run() != FALSE)
        {
            //i never reach this part..
        }
        else
        {
            //here load your view page...
        }
```